# Missing Bulk mode for adding Expressions to Z3 via Java-Wrapper

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native, z3

Looking a the class Solver.java in package com.microsoft.z3 one can see that the method ' public void add(BoolExpr... constraints)'
simply cycles over the constraints and for each calls Z3 via the Native-Interface. This poses  performance issues.

This issue is well known for mathematical Solvers like Gurobi or Cplex. They offer either a bulk versions of such methods on the Native-Interface or provide buffering for the whole model in the Java-Wrapper.
Upon a call to a 'update'-method the model is transferred to the native Code.

```
    {
        getContext().checkContextMatch(constraints);
        for (BoolExpr a : constraints)
        {
            Native.solverAssert(getContext().nCtx(), getNativeObject(),
                    a.getNativeObject());
        }
    }
```

Offering a real bulk-version of add-method where all constraints of the parameters are transferred to Z3-native-code in one go.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you thought this through! You can file a "feature request" at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues or better yet, submit a patch at: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/pulls

If it's a well-contained patch, I'm sure the developers will be happy to integrate it in!